# Is it safe to send login credentials using put or delete (vs post)?

Tags: javascript, html, api, rest, authentication

I'm making a RESTful API for a webapp.

Because some mobile browsers remove client-side cookies once a user exits the browser, I'm using local.storage to store a user's key which can be sent to API to authenticate a user.

Given that the key is long enough, changes frequently, and all communication happens over https, is it safe to send the key using put or delete? My understanding is that if I use get, the key could be left in browser history which could be used by a malicious user to gain access to the user's account. Post, in contrast, is much safer. How about put or delete?

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would send the key via the HTTP headers; that way it doesn't matter which method you use, be it GET, POST, PUT, etc.

See also: [`setRequestHeader()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#dom-xmlhttprequest-setrequestheader)

Answer (score -1):

If you use GET and have the key sent as a parameter then absolutely it is unsafe. Browsers will cache the URL meaning the key will be available in history. I would stick them in the header for some security.

If your really interested in being secure though you can use something like a challenge-response authentication pattern (or the many variants of this pattern). I guess you are somewhat on the right track since you mentioned your key changes frequently anyway. The real question is how are you grabbing that key in the first instance in the client (is that safe?)...